# Hibernate HQL attribute of a parameter in parameter list

Tags: hibernate, hql, named-query

I have an HQL like below. When I run this HQL, i get error. I want to use an object list as param. And I want use this objects attributes. I have solved this problem by using Criteria and DetachedCriteria but I wonder that there is any solution in HQL.

```
<named-query name="Book.findBooksByPropertyValue">
    <query>
        select book
        from Book book
        join book.bundleProperty bundleProperty
        join bundleProperty.property property
        left join bundleProperty.selectedProperty selectedProperty
        where
        property.code in :bundleProperty.property.code and 
        (bundleProperty.propertyValue in :bundleProperty.propertyValue or selectedProperty.id in :bundleProperty.selectedProperty.id)
    </query>
</named-query>


class Book()
{
    //...
    BundleProperty bundleProperty;
}

class BundleProperty()
{
    ...
    boolean propertySelective;
    Property property;
    String propertyValue;
    PropertyChoice selectedProperty;
}

class bookController()
{
    //...
    public List<Book> findBooks()
    {
        List<BundleProperty> bundleProperties = new ArrayList<>();
        for(PropertyBase propertyBase : selectedPropertyBases )
        {
            BundleProperty bundleProperty = new BundleProperty();
            bundleProperty.setProperty(propertyBase.getProperty());

            if(propertyBase.getProperty().isPropertySelective())
            {
                bundleProperty.setSelectedProperty(propertyBase.getSelectedProperty());
            }
            else
            {
                bundleProperty.setPropertyValue(propertyBase.getPropertyValue());
            }
            bundleProperties.add(bundleProperty);
        }

        return bookService.findBooksByPropertyValue(bundleProperties);
    }
}

class bookServiceImp()
{
    //...
    public List<Book> findBooksByPropertyValue(List<BundleProperty> bundleProperties)
    {
        return getSession().getNamedQuery("Book.findBooksByPropertyValue")
                .setParameterList("bundleProperty", bundleProperties)
                .list();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Make your query have 3 different parameters (`:value`, `:code` and `:id`), and when executing it, extract those 3 parameters from your BundleProperty object and set each of them as parameter.

Query:

```
select book
    from Book book
    join book.bundleProperty bundleProperty
    join bundleProperty.property property
    left join bundleProperty.selectedProperty selectedProperty
    where
    property.code in :codes and 
    (bundleProperty.propertyValue in :values or selectedProperty.id in :ids)
```

Code:

```
public List<Book> findBooksByPropertyValue(List<BundleProperty> bundleProperties) {
    List<String> codes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    for (BundleProperty bp : bundleProperties) {
        codes.add(bp.getProperty().getCode());
        ids.add(bp.getSelectedProperty().getId());
        values.add(bp.getPropertyValue());
    }

    return getSession().getNamedQuery("Book.findBooksByPropertyValue")
            .setParameterList("ids", ids)
            .setParameterList("codes", codes)
            .setParameterList("values", values)
            .list();
}
```

Comment: Relation between the three of these params are important, like which value is amongs to which id. How can we define the relation?

Comment: I have amended my answer, but I'm not sure that this is what you actually want. If this is not, then you should first think about what the SQL query should look like, and then translate it to HQL, if it's possible.